# How do I handle callbacks when using selectors?

Tags: swift, event-handling, selector, viewmodel

I'm placing my logic code in a `viewModel`. The `view` calls one method in the `viewController`. That method then calls the rest of the methods in the `viewModel` by using `#selectors`. This works fine up until the `tableView` needs to be reloaded with `tableView.reloadData()`. That part obviously needs to be in the `view`.

Normally, this would be accomplished by using multiple closures. But as `#selectors` can't have parameters I can't have a `completion()` callback in the last method that is called. So, my question is, how do I get around this problem? Is there any good alternatives to using `#selectors`? Should I have an observer in the `view` subscribing to the last method of the `viewModel`? Is RxSwift an alternative? Or is there a workaround using `#selectors`?

Comment: So why exactly can't you actually use closures?

Comment: Also, are you sure that your `view` _calls_ method in `viewController`. That seems illegal in a first place. It's hard to tell what problem you're having and why you're using objc selectors in Swift environment.

Comment: Please include some code illustrating your case, because it's really hard to follow your problem description. Especially focus on an example illustrating the limitation of `#selector` you mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RxSwift is a good alternative, but in case you need something not as heavy, the delegate pattern is what you need:

```
protocol ViewDelegate {
    // Other functions you might need
    func reloadTableView()
}

Then in your viewController, you implement these:

class ViewController: ViewDelegate {
    func reloadTableView() {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

And somewhere, in your view model you need to define the delegate:

```
weak var viewDelegate: ViewDelegate
```

As well as assign it when creating the classes:

```
let model = ViewModel()
let view = ViewController()

model.viewDelegate = view
```

Swift official documentation has a lot more on protocols: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html